# librtld_db failed to initialize

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, solaris

1. I have big project with old and mess Makefiles on Solaris.
2. I wrote CMakeLists.txt for the same project, based on those Makefiles.
3. I can compile old way to it's directory and get `MyBinary(1)`, and compile using CMake to another directory and get `MyBinary(2)`.
4. `ldd MyBinary(X)` are exactly the same in both variants (with different order of represented libraries, but same libraries one-to-one)
5. On Linux & Windows this CMake script works instead of old Makefiles without problems.

But on Solaris when I try to run `MyBinary(2)`, I always get error: `Illegal Instruction (core dumped)`, with next `pstack core`:

```
core 'core' of 1559:    ./MyBinary
 ffffffff7f728d20 ???????? (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
 0000000000000000 ???????? (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
pstack: warning: librtld_db failed to initialize; symbols from shared libraries will not be available
```

When I do the same with `MyBinary(1)`, it successfully runs.

Google hints that problem may be in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` / `PATH`. But when I put `MyBinary`(2) to location of `MyBinary(1)`, problem still there (but `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` / `PATH` reason should be resolved)

`man librtld_db` hints that `librtld_db` is runtime debug library, but I do next cmake commands:

```
CXX=CC CC=cc cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
```

So compiler is used the same as for MyBinary(1), version is `Release`. Inside CMake it has same instructions (including `-m64`).

So why do I get this `Illegal Instruction (core dumped)`?

Comment: What is the actual compile command that's run when you run CMake?  What is the actual compile command that's run when you run make?

Comment: @AndrewHenle, how can I get it with CMake? Do I need to provide special flag so it will print it out?

Comment: You can run `truss -f -a -vall -t\!all -texecve -o /path/to/output/file cmake ...` to trace all `exec` calls that start a new process to see what gets run.  You'd need to find all the ones that `exec` either `cc` or `CC` and parse out the arguments.  I suspect your compiler is getting passed incorrect arguments and is building a binary incompatible with your CPU.